# How to loop through each row of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I'm using an API to find information on smart contracts. Each Contract has a unique address and the information can be pulled by plugging it into an API link. Example:

'https://contract-api.dev/contracts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

I have a CSV with 1000 contract addresses. Example:

|  | Address |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2 |
| 1 | 0xa5409ec958c83c3f309868babaca7c86dcb077c1 |
| 2 | 0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7 |
| 3 | 0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48 |
| 4 | 0xa2327a938febf5fec13bacfb16ae10ecbc4cbdcf |
| ... | ... |

And this code allows me to get exactly what I want for one row,

```
    ADDRESS = df['Address'][0]
    total = requests.get(f"https://contract-api.dev/contracts/{ADDRESS}", headers={'CF-Access-Client-Id':  'xxxxxx.access', 'CF-Access-Client-Secret': 'xxxxx'}).json()
    total['deployment']['created_by_user']
```

Where the output is:

```
    '0x4f26ffbe5f04ed43630fdc30a87638d53d0b0876'
```

I just need to find a way to loop through every row and insert the contract Address into the API link, retrieve the "created_by_user" address, then move to the next row.

What do you think the best way to do this is?

Answer (score 0):

```
def retrieve_created_by_user(address_):
   return requests.get(f"https://contract-api.dev/contracts/{address_}", headers={'CF-Access-Client-Id':  'xxxxxx.access', 'CF-Access-Client-Secret': 'xxxxx'}).json()['deployment']['created_by_user']

for address in df['Address']:
    created_by_user = retrieve_created_by_user(address)
    ...
```

Or since it can probably take a bit you can use a progress bar like [tqdm](https://tqdm.github.io/):

```
from tqdm import tqdm
 
for address is tqdm(df['Address']):
    created_by_user = retrieve_created_by_user(address)
    ...
```

Here do with that rows data whatever you plan to do.

If for some reason you want to be able to index the values (e.g. to restart from a manual index later) you can use `list(df['Address'])`.

Comment: Incredible! Thank you!! Progress bar is a great addition.